# 403 Forbidden from xively api SIM900 shield

Tags: gsm, gprs, xively

I use SIM900 shield with arduino UNO. I try to make conection with xively server. I follow the instructions from: http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/GSMExamplesXivelyClient?from=Tutorial.GSMExamplesPachubeClient

This example is for other GSM shield, but it show me how should look like conection with xively. I've made such code:

```
gsm.SimpleWrite("PUT /v2/feeds/");
gsm.SimpleWrite(1055165076);
gsm.SimpleWriteln(".csv HTTP/1.1");
gsm.SimpleWrite("Host: api.xively.com\n");
gsm.SimpleWrite("X-ApiKey: ");
gsm.SimpleWriteln("j2AlGTCLxJzArQhL7dqrLYG6BtJd5aI8LoJmc7ha0mgsPWPD");
//gsm.SimpleWrite("User-Agent: ");
//gsm.SimpleWrite(arduino);
gsm.SimpleWrite("Content-Length: ");
gsm.SimpleWriteln(10);
gsm.SimpleWrite("Content-Type: text/csv\n");
gsm.SimpleWriteln("Connection: close");
gsm.SimpleWriteln("");

gsm.SimpleWrite("sensor1,");
gsm.SimpleWriteln(16);
gsm.SimpleWrite(end_c);
```

By this code I would like to send sensor1 value : 16.

After execution of this code xively server make my some answer:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Mon, 25 Nov 2013 08:19:27 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunkd
oncin ls

4
Yud o aetencesr emsin oacs hsrsuc
```

On web https://xively.com/dev/docs/api/communicating/http/http_status_codes/ i found that error mean:

403     Forbidden   Xively understands your request, but refuses to fulfil it. An accompanying error message should explain why.(NOTE: in the V2 API, this is the error returned when the API rate limit is exceeded.)

If I change for example API-KEY, server give me 404 error. I'm trying to solve this problem for several days. Maybe someone has an idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "Accept: */*"

I believe your Content-Length should be 11 (including newline).